# VLookup using Microsoft Visual Basics and excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a macro to complete a vlookup using one workbook with two worksheet.  When the code runs the vlookup part, a screen pops up labeled **Update Values: MODs**.  It then want me to open a spreadsheet.  I don't need to open a spreadsheet.  I would like the program to run where it uses the spreadsheet in the open workbook labeled MODs.

```
Sub VLOOKUP_Formula_3()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lr As Integer
lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("AD2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,2,0)"
sh.Range("AE2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,3,0)"
sh.Range("AF2").Value = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,4,0)"

sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).FillDown
sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Copy
sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

It this image you will see a picture of the spreadsheet and visual Basics.

Comment: Looks like this code is your PERSONAL.XLSB workbook. You likely want `Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`  or to move the code to the workbook containing the `MODs` sheet. The behavior you're seeing is because the PERSONAL.xlsb workbook has no worksheet named `MODs`.

Comment: Side note: `Dim lr As Long`, not `Integer`. Also you don't need to use `.FillDown`. Just write the formula to the entire range: `sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,2,0)"`. Neither do you need to use the clipboard: `sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Value = sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Value`.

Comment: This really helps.  The macro ran when changing to the active notebook.  Now, I added the Macro to my personal excel spreadsheet and labeled the tab MODs and updated the code to back to read ThisWorkbook but it returns nothing.

Comment: Can you offer any advice.  I can't figure out how to add a new picture.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize what BigBen said, move the macro into the workbook that has the sheets as opposed to your personal workbook, you can see this as the last set of dropdowns in the pane from your image. Right click there, insert module, and copy and paste the following code into the module. I took your code and tweaked it according to BigBen's comments which have generally good macro-writing hygiene. You don't need to `.filldown` or use the clipboard to achieve what you want to accomplish. I hope this helps.

```
Sub VLOOKUP_Formula_3()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim lr As Long
lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("AD2:AD" & lr).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,2,0)"
sh.Range("AE2:AE" & lr).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,3,0)"
sh.Range("AF2:AF" & lr).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AC2,'MODs'!A:D,4,0)"

sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Value = sh.Range("AD2:AF" & lr).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen This really helps. The macro ran when changing to the active notebook. Now, I added the MODs tab in my personal excel spreadsheet and labeled the tab MODs and updated the code to back to read ThisWorkbook but it returns nothing.   Can you advise?

Comment: LBroussard Move the macro to the workbook with your data, not the other way around.